# How to loop 10 times a single test in selenium using serenity framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

i would like to know is there any way to run a single test of selenium for n number of times.
i could do this using JMeter but my task requirement is to use selenium with serenity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `serenity-junit5` to achieve this goal. JUnit5 has `@RepeatedTest(n)` to run a test in n times. Code example:

```java
import net.serenitybdd.junit5.SerenityJUnit5Extension;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Managed;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

@ExtendWith(SerenityJUnit5Extension.class)
public class GoToGoogle {

    @Managed
    WebDriver driver;

    @RepeatedTest(2)
    void name() {
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```